# SQL alwaysON and WSFC

Tags: sql, cluster, alwayson

I have a WSFC configured on 2 (hardware)nodes with SQL AlwaysOn group.
The problem is, if the node Where I have created the cluster goes down the cluster is not available for second node and here AlwaysOn Group is also not available.
Is there any option to set second WSFC node as a backup for Main node?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you don't have your cluster quorum set correctly, so the cluster goes down when one of the two nodes goes down.  Configure a file share witness for your quorum (e. g. http://blogs.technet.com/b/askpfeplat/archive/2012/06/27/clustering-what-exactly-is-a-file-share-witness-and-when-should-i-use-one.aspx) and you should be in better shape.

Comment: Today you may also like to look at cloud witness: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/failover-clustering/deploy-cloud-witness